# Analytic Continuation of zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

I know that

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ is convergent if Re(s)>1.

And I read that it can be defined continuously for $s\in \mathbb C$ if $1\neq Re(s)>0$. How can this be true?

If $s=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\zeta(\frac{1}{2})=\infty$, just as $\zeta(1)$. So why we can redefine $\zeta$ at $\frac{1}{2}$ to make it continuous but not at $1$?

Comment: It is exactly the same idea as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ ($|z| < 1$)

Comment: The relation  (when $\text{Re}s>1 $) between the zeta function $\zeta(\cdot)$ and the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(\cdot)$ *still* holds for $\text{Re}s>0 $ giving the desired value for $\zeta(1/2)$: $$\zeta(s):=\frac{\eta(s) } {1-2^{1-s}},\quad \text{Re}s>0.\quad (*)$$

Comment: @reuns thanks for your answer, but I dont see the connection. Can you explain? The above series diverges for s=1/2, but still we are able to assign a fixed value to make a continuous? How can this happen?

Comment: @OlivierOloa thanks for your answer. I also found this argument in the internet but I am a bit confused, since for s=1/2 the series is equal to $\infty$ but we are still able to assign a fixed value for $s=1/2$ to make it continuous around $s=1/2$. How does this work?

Comment: We **define** $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1/2$ with $(*)$ above since *the right hand side* makes sense.

Comment: Do you realize $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ converges and is analytic only for $|z| < 1$, but once you know $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ you got the analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ ? For $\zeta(s)$ it works the same way.

Comment: @reuns thank you. It makes more sense now :)

Comment: @reuns I have another question left. Since $\{z\in \mathbb C : Re(z)>1\}$ and $\{z\in \mathbb C : 0<Re(z)<1\}$ are disjoint we could define $\zeta(s)$ on the second domain as any homomorphic function we want to get a homomorphic continuation? I cant believe that this is true, but why this shouldnt be the case?